# How to add search functionality to Facebook's placePickerViewController?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am currently using Facebook's `placePickerViewController` in my iOS app. What I am trying to do is add search functionality to this controller.

My current solution calls `loadData` each time a new character is typed into the search input. The search itself is handled by the `placePickerViewController:shouldIncludePlace` method. This solution works, but it has many negative side effects. For one, the `loadData` method makes round-trip to the server and back for each new character, which is inefficient at best. It also occasionally crashes if the user types their search query too quickly.

The Facebook `friendPickerViewController` has a method called `updateView` which updates a friends list with pre-cached data. Unfortunately, `placePickerViewController` does not have an equivalent method.

Has anybody implemented search in this controller? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!